# Django altering multiple objects with the same attribute on a form

Tags: python, django

I am trying to alter the attribute for several objects using a single input. The model setup is as follows:

```py
class Entry(models.Model):
    Person =  models.ForeignKey(
        Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True
    )
    group = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, blank=True, null=True, choices=Constants().group()
    )
    station = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, blank=True, null=True, choices=Constants().station()
    )



class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    home_address = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
```

The idea is that each person can enter an event and is assigned a group. Each group has multiple people. Then each group is assigned a station. I attempted to create another relational model so each instance of the Entry class did not contain the group-station assignment however I could not get that to work.

The goal is to display on a table with the following columns: Group Station Entrants then for each row of the table the group # is displayed followed by the station as a drop down menu of numbers followed by the list of all the entrants in the model that have the same group #. Then when the form that the table is in is saved, the station is assigned to all the individual entry objects.

E.g.

```
    Group   Station     Entrants
      2     Select...   John Doe, Jane Doe, Etc.
      6     Select...   Bob, Dane, Harry Etc.
```

Comment: So what is the issue exactly? You don't know how to setup the relations? Or how to render the form?

Comment: Its both, I have been able to render the form however the specific problem is I can't figure out how to get the select field to apply the attribute to the objects listed to the right of them, at the moment I just have a dropdown menu as described in the original post with no functionality. I setup a formset but I'm not sure how to implement it HTML side to get it to save information as described.

Comment: Can you show the Profile model? In particular the group field? Any reason you don't use [built-in groups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#groups)? Also, you may need: [DAL](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#filtering-results-based-on-the-value-of-other-fields-in-the-form).

Comment: Profile model added to original post. The reason I stayed away from built in groups is that there eventually will be several events, meaning the same Entry model will be used for multiple events so there would be repeated information and it would get messy.